# Class specification for HTML details

Tags: html, css

I want to specify classes for details and it's summary, to create different behavior for different cases.

For example, I need two cases: details for screenshots and for some text categories.

But in that way it doesn't works:

```css
/* When spoiler is opened */

details.[open] summary .screenshot {
  background: #AC193D;
  color: #FFF;
}

details[open] summary .category {
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}


/* Add the custom marker in the default state. */

details summary:before .screenshot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  content: "";
  background-image: url(/images/spoiler.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

details summary:before .category {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<details class="category">
  <summary>some title</summary>
  some text
</details>

<details class="screenshot">
  <summary>some title 2</summary>
  some text 2
</details>
```

They are looks and works the same:
[image: screenshot of result]
<sub>(source: [pastexen.com](http://pastexen.com/i/nhx2rTS3XF.png))</sub>

When first one must be without image and must not change color on open.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it doesn't works" — this is not a good description of the problem. What doesn't work? You've got 4 different selectors in the CSS, which of them are not applying.

Comment: You haven't included any HTML in your question. For all we know, the problem is that the selectors simply don't match the HTML. Provide a real [mcve]. Preferably as a [live demo](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin, you are right. I'm fixed it.

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/  will pick up the straight up syntax errors in that CSS.

Comment: Also read https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators